Computing the voltage variation of a node in a linear circuit
I have the circuit shown below. I am trying to compute the variation of the node voltage \$V_{n1}\$ when the current sources attached at the output nodes change. This should be a straightforward thing to do, but I am not getting anywhere when using KCL and substitutions. So I resorted to using derivatives. However, the final result computed is wrong (when comparing it to simulation). This is likely because I am not accounting for dependencies correctly.

We can see that \$V_{n 1}\$ depends \$V_{p 1}\$ and \$V_{p 2}\$, which in turn
depend on \$I_{p 1}\$ and \$I_{p 2}\$.
\begin{equation}
  \Delta V_{n 1} = \frac{\partial V_{n 1}}{\partial V_{p 1}} \cdot
  \frac{\partial V_{p 1}}{\partial I_{p 1}} \cdot \Delta I_{p 1} +
  \frac{\partial V_{n 1}}{\partial V_{p 2}} \cdot \frac{\partial V_{p
  2}}{\partial I_{p 2}} \cdot \Delta I_{p 2}
\end{equation}
The KCL equation at node \$V_{n 1}\$ is:
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{V_{n 1} - V_{k 1}}{R^K_{11}} + \frac{V_{n 1} - V_{k 2}}{R^K_{21}} +
   \frac{V_{n 1} - V_{k 3}}{R^K_{31}} + \frac{V_{n 1} -
   V_{p 1}}{R^N_{11}} + \frac{V_{n 1} - V_{p 2}}{R^N_{12}}
   = 0 
\end{equation*}
Rearranging:
\begin{equation*}
 V_{n 1} \left( \underbrace{\underbrace{\frac{1}{R^K_{11}} +
   \frac{1}{R^K_{21}} + \frac{1}{R^K_{31}}}_{G^{^K}_{c 1}} +
   \underbrace{\frac{1}{R^N_{11}} + \frac{1}{R^N_{12}}}_{G^{^N}_{r
   1}}}_{G^{^{K, N}}_{c 1, r 1}} \right) = \left( \frac{V_{k 1}}{R^K_{11}} +
   \frac{V_{k 2}}{R^K_{21}} + \frac{V_{k 3}}{R^K_{31}} \right) + \left(
   \frac{V_{p 1}}{R^N_{11}} + \frac{V_{p 2}}{R^N_{12}} \right) 
\end{equation*}
Let's compute the derivatives:
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial V_{n 1}}{\partial V_{p 1}} = \frac{G^N_{11}}{G^{^{K, N}}_{c
  1, r 1}}, \quad \frac{\partial V_{n 1}}{\partial V_{p 2}} =
  \frac{G^N_{12}}{G^{^{K, N}}_{c 1, r 1}}
\end{equation}
The KCL at node \$V_{p 1}\$ is:
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{V_{p 1} - V_{n 1}}{R^N_{11}} + \frac{V_{p 1} - V_{n 2}}{R^N_{21}} +
   I_{p 1} = 0 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 V_{p 1}  \left( \underbrace{\frac{1}{R^N_{11}} +
   \frac{1}{R^N_{21}}}_{G^{^N}_{c 1}} \right) = - I_{p 1} + \left( \frac{V_{n
   1}}{R^N_{11}} + \frac{V_{n 2}}{R^N_{21}} \right) 
\end{equation*}
Similarly, for \$V_{p 2}\$, we get:
\begin{equation*}
 V_{p 2}  \left( \underbrace{\frac{1}{R^N_{12}} +
   \frac{1}{R^N_{22}}}_{G^{^N}_{c 2}} \right) = - I_{p 2} + \left( \frac{V_{n
   1}}{R^N_{12}} + \frac{V_{n 2}}{R^N_{22}} \right) 
\end{equation*}
Let's compute the derivatives:
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{\partial V_{p 1}}{\partial I_{p 1}} = - \frac{1}{G^{^N}_{c 1}}, \quad
   \frac{\partial V_{p 2}}{\partial I_{p 2}} = - \frac{1}{G^{^N}_{c 2}} 
\end{equation*}
Finally:
\begin{equation*}
 \Delta V_{n 1} = \left( \frac{G^N_{11}}{G^{^{K, N}}_{c 1, r 1}} \right)
   \cdot \left( - \frac{1}{G^{^N}_{c 1}} \right) \cdot \Delta I_{p 1} + \left(
   \frac{G^N_{12}}{G^{^{K, N}}_{c 1, r 1}} \right) \cdot \left( -
   \frac{1}{G^{^N}_{c 2}} \right) \cdot \Delta I_{p 2} 
\end{equation*}

Is that 10 resistors total and just 2 current sinks? Or is there something more general I'm missing? I don't see a problem in the first case.

It's supposed to be general. The figure is supposed to make it easy to write the basic equation structure.

@periblepsis, I have tried to formulate the problem using derivatives to make easier to handle but I still am not able to get the correct expression.

Your notation isn't as easy as I think it should be for me to read with understanding. I'm guessing that you have $k$ voltage sources on the left and these connect to $n$ nodes via resistor values that may be different depending on the node they are connected towards. These $n$ nodes are, themselves, further connected to $p$ nodes via, again, resistors that may be different. Each $p$ node has a current sink. So $n\cdot\left(k+p\right)$ resistors. Am I still missing what you are writing about? Have you read this from me, yet?

@periblepsis, for the sake of simplicity, ignore the general case and just the figure above.

Why can't you use the superposition theorem?

@LeonhardEuler I can't. Because you have two resistors labeled R11, for example, and I don't know if these are different resistors with possibly different values or if you intentionally labeled them the same because their values are the same. Like I said, your notation is hard for me to follow. I think they are different. But I'm not sure.

@periblepsis, they are different resistors. Thats why I have a superscript on the R to distinguish them, K for the set on the left, and N for the set on the right.

@LeonhardEuler Then I don't see any problem. I'll write it up.

@LeonhardEuler Done. I just picked random values. That the values matched first time I tried it shows that I followed a process, rigorously. This all can be done using the method I applied in that link I offered earlier, though, if you want to automate things for arbitrary graphs.

Are all the different bits of circuits shown in your diagram meant to be different parts of the same circuit? Or 4 different circuits? Why do the current sources use the diamond symbol (usually representing a controlled current source) instead of the round symbol (usually representing an independent current source)?


for the sake of simplicity, ignore the general case and just the
figure above.

Using SymPy:
e1 = Eq( Vn1/Rn11 + Vn1/Rn21 + Vn1/Rn31 + Vn1/Rp11 + Vn1/Rp12, Vk1/Rn11 + Vk2/Rn21 + Vk3/Rn31 + Vp1/Rp11 + Vp2/Rp12 )
e2 = Eq( Vn2/Rn12 + Vn2/Rn22 + Vn2/Rn32 + Vn2/Rp21 + Vn2/Rp22, Vk1/Rn12 + Vk2/Rn22 + Vk3/Rn32 + Vp1/Rp21 + Vp2/Rp22 )
e3 = Eq( Vp1/Rp11 + Vp1/Rp21 + Ip1, Vn1/Rp11 + Vn2/Rp21 )
e4 = Eq( Vp2/Rp12 + Vp2/Rp22 + Ip2, Vn1/Rp12 + Vn2/Rp22 )
ans = solve( [ e1, e2, e3, e4 ], [ Vn1, Vn2, Vp1, Vp2 ] )
for i,j in ans.items():
    i,j.subs({Vk1:5,Vk2:7,Vk3:11,Ip1:.45,Ip2:.54,Rn11:23,Rn21:27,Rn31:31,Rn12:17,Rn22:19,Rn32:15,Rp11:105,Rp21:91,Rp12:75,Rp22:26})
(Vn1, 4.28171030684488)
(Vn2, 4.23585739573948)
(Vp1, -17.6803537526759)
(Vp2, -6.17808145882744)

Now using LTspice:

Sorry about not being as neat in drawing out the schematic. But at least the results match up just fine.
added clarification

the goal is to have an expression for how much the voltage varies at a
particular node when the current sources change.

Suppose I want to know by what % Vn2 will change if I make a specific +5% change in Ip1?
sens = (derivative(ans[Vn2],Ip1)*Ip1/ans[Vn2])
sens.subs({Vk1:5,Vk2:7,Vk3:11,Ip1:.45,Ip2:.54,Rn11:23,Rn21:27,Rn31:31,Rn12:17,Rn22:19,Rn32:15,Rp11:105,Rp21:91,Rp12:75,Rp22:26})*5.0
-1.63833719188176

You can see the "+5" multiplying the sensitivity equation above. The result says that I should expect to see about -1.64% change. Let's see:

(4.16646-4.23586)/4.23586
-0.0163839220370834

Yeah. Multiplied by 100 to put it into % notation, that seems to work, too.

Thanks. The point was not to solve the circuit. The goal is to have an expression for how much the voltage varies at a particular node when the current sources change.

@LeonhardEuler That's a sensitivity equation. I write elsewhere here about those, as well. That can be directly derived from the solution.

@LeonhardEuler Like I said before, I'm having trouble understanding you. I'll add a short demonstration at the end.

@LeonhardEuler Done. Anything else I didn't understand that you needed to know?
